# Styles for elements that contain elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Is it possible to have different pre style only for those pre tags, that have a code tag inside?

```
<pre>Lorem Ipsum</pre>
```

should be styled differently than

```
<pre><code>code</code></pre>
```

but on the pre element.

Comment: This is called a "parent selector".  CSS cannot do this (yet).  You'd need to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Sadly no: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector